# Generic Logistic Regression in R

Tags: r, logistic-regression

I was wondering if you can create a generic version of logistic regression, by which I mean one that will allow the use of differently name variables in the prediction data set.

Comment: The idea of putting a placeholder into a statistical model doesn't really make much sense to me. Perhaps you could explain what you mean. This may be more of a stats.stackexchange.com question.

Comment: Sure: I'm currently trying to analyze data from multiple sources. Since the sources all have different variable names and locations, and the data are called different names, can there just be placeholder variables in the regression that take the values from the excel file I would be importing? This would (in my mind) remove the hurdle of constantly having to rename variables before creating the model

Comment: Oh ok, so as long as the variables represent the same variable and are on the same scale you can just train a logit model (that's the nickname for logistic) and then rename your new variables when you import them later

Comment: Though someone reading can follow the question but explaining the question with small sample example will be much better for future reader of this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
require(mtcars) # this represents your training data
train <- mtcars

logit <- glm(vs~mpg, data = train, family = "binomial")

generic.logit <- function(mpg, data=test){
  test          <- data
  test$mpg      <- mpg
  mypredictions <- predict(logit, test)
  return(mypredictions)
}

test <- mtcars
test$random_name <- test$mpg
test$mpg         <- NULL # this represents your prediction data set

generic.logit(data=test, mpg = test$random_name)



      Mazda RX4       Mazda RX4 Wag          Datsun 710      Hornet 4 Drive   Hornet Sportabout             Valiant 
      0.2056113           0.2056113           0.9803557           0.3777768          -0.7843397          -1.0425879 
     Duster 360           Merc 240D            Merc 230            Merc 280           Merc 280C          Merc 450SE 
     -2.6781592           1.6690173           0.9803557          -0.5691330          -1.1717119          -1.7742908 
     Merc 450SL         Merc 450SLC  Cadillac Fleetwood Lincoln Continental   Chrysler Imperial            Fiat 128 
     -1.3869187          -2.2907871          -4.3567720          -4.3567720          -2.5059938           5.1123255 
    Honda Civic      Toyota Corolla       Toyota Corona    Dodge Challenger         AMC Javelin          Camaro Z28 
      4.2514984           5.7579458           0.4208181          -2.1616630          -2.2907871          -3.1085728 
   Pontiac Firebird           Fiat X1-9       Porsche 914-2        Lotus Europa      Ford Pantera L        Ferrari Dino 
         -0.5691330           2.9172165           2.3576790           4.2514984          -2.0325390          -0.3539262 
      Maserati Bora          Volvo 142E 
         -2.3768698           0.3777768
```

Comment: It's generally unwise to use `$` inside functions. Better to use `[[varname]]` or `[['varname']]` depending on goal.

Comment: @42 I never had a problem with it. Any particular reason?

Comment: what is this function even doing? Why not `predict(logit, transform(mtcars, mpg=test$random_name))`

Comment: It locks you in to only ever using your "generic" function with a variable named `"mpg"`, so it's not really "generic".

Comment: @42 It's an example and is based on the needs of the OP as he explained them to me in the comments. Also, mpg is a variable name in a function... It can be assigned to a variable of any name. Also I don't know what you meant by "you in to only"?